# Change position level and timestamp zerolog golang

Tags: go, zerolog

i'm using zerolog for logging and got complain because the format log not same like before, i'm trying refactor from other language to golang.
is possible change position level and timestamp ?

this is my code :
`

```
consoleWriter := zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, NoColor: 
true, TimeFormat: time.RFC3339}

consoleWriter.FormatLevel = func(i interface{}) string {
    return strings.ToUpper(fmt.Sprintf("[ %-6s] -", i))
}
consoleWriter.FormatTimestamp = func(i interface{}) string {
    return strings.ToUpper(fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", i))
}

if cfg.Logger.WriteLogger {
    multi = zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(consoleWriter, file)
} else {
    defer file.Close()
    multi = zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(consoleWriter)
}

logger := zerolog.New(multi).Level(zerolog.TraceLevel).
    With().
    Timestamp().
    Logger()
 logger.Info().Msg("this is message")
```

`

and i got result :

> [2024-01-16T13:24:05+07:00] [ INFO  ] - this is message

Is it possible to change the position so that the result looks like:

> [ INFO  ] [2024-01-16T13:24:05+07:00] - this is message

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PartsOrder](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rs/zerolog#ConsoleWriter) to do this; you will also need to tweak your formatters to get the `-` in the right place ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IyQnbSdd5qS)).

```
func main() {
    consoleWriter := zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, NoColor: true, TimeFormat: time.RFC3339}

    consoleWriter.FormatLevel = func(i interface{}) string {
        return strings.ToUpper(fmt.Sprintf("[ %-6s]", i))
    }
    //consoleWriter.FormatTimestamp = func(i interface{}) string {
    //  return strings.ToUpper(fmt.Sprintf("[%s] -", i))
    //}
    consoleWriter.TimeFormat = "[" + time.RFC3339 + "] - "
    consoleWriter.PartsOrder = []string{
        zerolog.LevelFieldName,
        zerolog.TimestampFieldName,
        zerolog.CallerFieldName,
        zerolog.MessageFieldName,
    }
    logger := zerolog.New(consoleWriter).Level(zerolog.TraceLevel).
        With().
        Timestamp().
        Logger()
    logger.Info().Msg("this is message")
}
```

Output:

```
[ INFO  ] [2024-01-16T21:11:39+13:00] -  this is message
```